# Org-roam case-insensitive search

Tags: search, org-roam

Org-roam's `org-roam-node-find` and `org-roam-node-insert` functions both match node titles case-sensitively. To find a node called "JavaScript" I can't just type lowercase `j TAB`, I have to type uppercase `J TAB`.

I'm using Emacs without any custom completion framework and I'd rather not globally set completions to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following config to override the behaviour of `org-roam-node-read` to be case-insensitive:

```el
(defun case-insensitive-org-roam-node-read (orig-fn &rest args)
  (let ((completion-ignore-case t))
    (apply orig-fn args)))
    
(advice-add 'org-roam-node-read :around #'case-insensitive-org-roam-node-read)
```

The `org-roam-node-read` function is called by both `org-roam-node-find` and `org-roam-node-insert`. The above change temporarily sets the `completion-ignore-case` variable before running the original `org-roam-node-read` function.